Can't use management API with JMS to change address settings
I am quite new to the world of JMS and ActiveMQ Artemis, and I'm struggling to make use of the management API to send a JMS message to my stand alone broker.
I am using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.38.0.
I want to update the address settings without using broker.xml, but I keep getting null as a reply, and the settings clearly don't change when I go to test them.
I followed along with a similar post and was able to come up with this bit of code:
try (JMSContext context = activeMQConnectionFactory.createContext(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
            //You MUST explicitly create this queue for management operations.
            Queue managementQueue = context.createQueue("activemq.management");

            Message message = context.createMessage();
            JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(
                message,
                ResourceNames.BROKER,    // Targetted Resource
                "addAddressSettings",    // Operation to invoke
                "ri.trips1",             // Address match
                null,                    // Dead letter address (DLA)
                null,                    // Expiry address
                -1L,                     // Expiry delay
                true,                    // Last value queue
                7,                       // Max delivery attempts
                -1L,                     // Max size bytes
                0,                       // Page size bytes
                -1,                      // Page max cache size
                1000L,                   // Redelivery delay
                1.0,                     // Redelivery multiplier
                -1L,                     // Max redelivery delay
                -1L,                     // Slow consumer threshold
                false,                   // Slow consumer policy
                null,                    // Slow consumer notification interval
                -1L,                     // Min large message size
                -1L,                     // Consumer window size
                null,                    // Auto-create queues
                true,                    // Auto-create addresses
                false,                   // Auto-delete queues
                false,                   // Auto-delete addresses
                true                     // Auto-delete created queues
            );
            context.createProducer().send(managementQueue, message);

            Message response = context.createConsumer(managementQueue).receive(5000);
            if (response != null && JMSManagementHelper.hasOperationSucceeded(response)) {
                System.out.println("Address settings applied successfully.");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Failed to apply address settings");
            }
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

The code block here is always resolving to failed because the response is always null. However, it is creating the address activemq.management just fine.

I think you should authenticate the user connecting to the management queue and check that he has sufficient permissions

The problem here is the way you're sending the request and receiving the reply. There's nothing to correlate the request with the response so you're not actually receiving a response. You could use a QueueRequestor as is demonstrated in the management example from ActiveMQ Artemis or you could stick with the JMSContext and correlate the response yourself, e.g.:
try (JMSContext context = activeMQConnectionFactory.createContext(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
   // You MUST explicitly create this queue for management operations.
   Queue managementQueue = context.createQueue("activemq.management");

   Message message = context.createMessage();
   JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(message, ResourceNames.BROKER, ...);
   Queue responseQueue = context.createTemporaryQueue();
   message.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);
   context.createProducer().send(managementQueue, message);
   Message response = context.createConsumer(responseQueue).receive(5000);
   if (response != null && JMSManagementHelper.hasOperationSucceeded(response)) {
      System.out.println("Address settings applied successfully.");
   } else {
      System.err.println("Failed to apply address settings");
   }
} catch (JMSException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}

Also, it's worth noting that the addAddressSettings method you're using is deprecated. I encourage you to use this one instead which takes flexible JSON input, e.g.
try (JMSContext context = activeMQConnectionFactory.createContext(JMSContext.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)) {
   //You MUST explicitly create this queue for management operations.
   Queue managementQueue = context.createQueue("activemq.management");
   Message message = context.createMessage();
   String json = """
      {
         "maxDeliveryAttempts": "7",
         "maxSizeBytes": "-1",
         "pageSizeBytes": "0",
         "redeliveryDelay": "1000"         
      }
      """;
   JMSManagementHelper.putOperationInvocation(message, ResourceNames.BROKER, "addAddressSettings", "ri.trips1", json);
   Queue responseQueue = context.createTemporaryQueue();
   message.setJMSReplyTo(responseQueue);
   context.createProducer().send(managementQueue, message);

   Message response = context.createConsumer(responseQueue).receive(5000);
   if (response != null && JMSManagementHelper.hasOperationSucceeded(response)) {
      System.out.println("Address settings applied successfully.");
   } else {
      System.err.println("Failed to apply address settings");
   }
} catch (JMSException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}


Thanks Justin for the answer, this is working and has also lowered my total LOC on this. Appreciate the help.
